# Processing file paths with parentheses with Python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

The paths of the files I want to process contain parentheses in them.

```
path = "/dir/file (with parentheses).txt"
```

I'm trying to process them in Python as follows:

```
subprocess.call("./process %s" % path, shell=True)
```

However, I get the following error

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

How can I pass the correct string to process the proper path?

Comment: Do you need shell=True?  If not it will likely work fine with making the args a list and not letting the shell trip on special characters

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
subprocess.call('./process "%s"' % path, shell=True)
```

I guess problem is more with space in file name. File names with spaces in them should be enclosed in quotes like this `./process "foo bar.txt"` or escaped like this `./process foo\ bar.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `shell=True`. It's trouble-prone (as in the OP) and enables [shell injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_injection#Shell_injection).

Do it like this:

```
subprocess.call(["./process", path])
```

If you insist on using `shell=True`, read the [Security Considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#security-considerations) in the python documentation, and make sure you use `shlex.quote` to correctly escape all metacharacters.